# Is it possible to create new tags in Mako?

Tags: python, mako

New to mako, didn't find in the docs...

One of the stuff I'd like to do with that is:

```
<%mytag n=12>
blabla ${x}
</%mytag>
```

which works like the following:

if the `X[n]` (here, `X[12]`) variable is an int or string then render the content with `x = X[12]`
=> With `X[12] = 23`, it'd render:  `blabla 23`

else if `X[n]` is a list, then do a `for` loop, repeating the content for each value of `x in X[n]`
=> With `X[12] = [1, 2, 'bla']`, it'd render:

```
blabla 1
blabla 2
blabla bla
```

Please try to answer the main question (is it possible to do custom tags?) if possible, before giving advice on how to do what I want to do, thanks :)

Comment: Why make new tags when Mako gives you all of python?

Comment: Easy: make it doable by non-pythonistas

Comment: @SlaterTyranus could you please post an answer on how to do the example I gave with python code in Mako?

Comment: This probably is the closest, you can define a def and then pass embedded content to it: http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#calling-a-def-with-embedded-content-and-or-other-defs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["namespaces"](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/namespaces.html) doc seem to describe what you are after, specifically:

> Namespaces can also import regular Python functions from modules. These callables need to take at least one argument, `context`, an instance of `Context`. A module file some/module.py might contain the callable:
>
> ```
> def my_tag(context):
>     context.write("hello world")
>     return ''
> ```
>
> A template can use this module via:
>
> ```
> <%namespace name="hw" module="some.module"/>
>
> ${hw.my_tag()}
> ```

..and:

> The "custom tag" format is intended mainly for namespace functions
>   which recognize body content, which in Mako is known as a “def with
>   embedded content”:
>
> ```
> <%mynamespace:somefunction arg1="some argument" args="x, y">
>     Some record: ${x}, ${y}
> </%mynamespace:somefunction>
> ```